# Laravel Virtual host issue

Tags: laravel, url, request, phpmyadmin, virtualhost

Facing issue in Laravel virtual host
I made virtual host by name "first-app". now when i hit in url this "http://first-app/"
it throws me this error

```
make(Kernel::class); $response = $kernel->handle( $request = Request::capture() )->send(); $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

how to resolve this issue

Comment: What error are you getting? You literally put the `index.php` code in there...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put **.test** into your domain name like http://first-app.test and other than please make sure PHP is enabled and linked to your site

Comment: I tried but didn't work . secondly i make a new virtual host with domain "http://www.mylaravelapp.com/" by this url it open up and show all the directories folder also when i add "/public" it again throughs me that "kernal error" but not showing the actual site.